# How to setup SNI on with NGINX Ingress Controller and ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, sni

I have a k8s cluster running on AWS EKS. I am using it to deploy a number of web applications, with each web app with its own domain name. I decided to use NGINX Ingress Controller to load balance these applications on multiple host names.

I set up my ingress controller using [these](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/) manifests and configured my deployment, service and ingress manifests and managed to get all of my apps running.

However I couldn't find how to set up SNI on my Ingress Controller. Since each ingress has a different host name, I have to use a different SSL Certificate for each underlying service.

Are there any instructions on how to do this?

What should I add to each manifest in order to get it working?

And is it possible to do it using ACM (AWS Certificate Manager) Certificates?